# WP_Query with meta_value_num and meta_query not paged correctly

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a strange thing with my WP_Query, where isn't paged correctly.

```
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => $limit, // 10
    'paged' => $page, // paged param
    'order' => $order, // ASC
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'ma_rate_percents',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'ma_rating_up',
            'compare' => '>',
            'value' => 0,
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'ma_rating_down',
            'compare' => '>',
            'value' => 0,
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    ),
    'fields' => 'ids'
);
$posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

In my example i get 412 results in $posts->found_posts and on first page i see 10 post id's. If i go to page=2 i get already 10 post id's, but with the last 2 ID's by page 1, on page 3 i get 4 ID's of page 2 and so on.

What's wrong with this Query? I'm also resetted the query with wp_reset_query() on the end, but nothing helps. Anyone an idea?

Comment: This should be moved to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for note. i don't know how i can move this posting, so i have add a new one on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: I've flagged the post, some mod will move it ;)